# Import Firebase User with Custom Claims

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I am trying to export and import user using the firebase CLI as per [docs available here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#file_format). My problem is that I want to also export the user claims, or at least be able to include custom claims when importing the user.

Basically to export I run on the CLI:

```
firebase auth:export test.json --format=json
```

And to import I run on the CLI:

```
firebase auth:import test.json \ --hash-algo:scrypt
```

The exported users don't hold the custom claims information.

At the moment, I am working with 2 custom claims, admin and access, pretty much as [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_without_passwords).

The problem is that I was not able to include the claims on the file without having an error returned. Is it feasible to import users with custom claims, if not, what is the correct procedure?

Comment: Can you share some code? It’s hard to understand your problem like this

Comment: added information on the code I am running on the cli, it is what is mentioned on the docs.

Comment: can confirm that `auth:export` does not include the custom claims.

Comment: Same issue here. Would love to get user claims when exporting auth users, but can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

If the claims are not exported by the CLI, then you will have to use the Firebase Admin SDK to [work with custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  Your code will iterate each UID, fetch the claims and store them somewhere, then update the claims when it's time to import.

Comment: Not the solution I am looking for. The first time the app is deployed, I must be able to deploy it with an user with admin claims, otherwise the user will never be able to login. The idea is similar to the deploy app such as Joomla, Wordpress, etc. You set the information of an admin user in order to continue.

Comment: If the CLI doesn't perform the import and export the way you'd like, I'd say this is likely your only option, unless you want to modify the CLI.  Source code is here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools